# Turn off "stop executable" dialog in xcode when running app?

Tags: xcode

The "stop executable" dialog that comes up every time I have an app already running in xcode and rebuild and run is really annoying me. Is it possible to turn this off and auto-stop any running apps?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: They've added an option in Xcode 4! Awesome!

Looks like there is no way

Answer (score 0):

You can hit shift-cmd-enter to kill a running app, that's the "speedup" I use. Don't know if it's faster than hitting enter when that dialog pops up though.